# How to typeset function restrictions

Tags: math-mode

I wonder how to typeset the restriction of a function to some subdomain, a la `$f|_A$` or `$f\restriction_A$` , but with the vertical bar being as big as possible.

Comment: It seems that one can just use \big| or \Big|. But is there something which chooses the optimal size (or can there not be such a thing)?

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: For `\restriction`, `\usepackage{amssymb}`.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev Your answer is the best - why don't you make it one?

Comment: @AriBrodsky It doesn't actually answer the OP's question (though it might be useful for folks like me who came to the page looking to answer the question restricted to its title :)

Comment: A related question solved my problem better: [One more question regarding “function restriction”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43951/25546)

Answer (score 65):

If you want the vertical bar to be at least `\big`, the following doesn't have the spacing issues of Ulrich's solution:

```
\newcommand\restr[2]{{% we make the whole thing an ordinary symbol
  \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace % automatically resize the bar with \right
  #1 % the function
  \vphantom{\big|} % pretend it's a little taller at normal size
  \right|_{#2} % this is the delimiter
  }}
```

If you don't need the extra height for normal size symbols, comment the `\vphantom` line.

Use it as `\restr{f}{A}`.

The above code works best in display style. In other styles (particularly text style) it's likely better to remove the phantom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\restr[2]{{% we make the whole thing an ordinary symbol
  \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace % automatically resize the bar with \right
  #1 % the function
  \littletaller % pretend it's a little taller at normal size
  \right|_{#2} % this is the delimiter
  }}

\newcommand{\littletaller}{\mathchoice{\vphantom{\big|}}{}{}{}}

\begin{document}

\[
\restr{f}{U}=\frac{\restr{g}{U}}{\restr{h}{U}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought you had a principle to always suppress end-line spaces with `%`, even in math mode, for the sake of “uniformity”. But perhaps that principle is less than a decade old? `;-)`

Comment: @Gaussler I leave as an exercise to the reader to explain why spaces here are not relevant. `;-)`

Comment: I know they’re not making any difference for commands intended for math mode, but look at your own comments [right here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/564506/19809). `;-)`

Answer (score 33):

Does `$\left.f\right|_A$` provide what you are looking for?

Comment: Hello @Lustique, is there a way to add another condition below? For example A and below B?

Answer (score 5):

How about `\newcommand\restr[2]{\ensuremath{\left.#1\right|_{#2}}}`, which can be used like this: `$\restr{f}{A}$`?

(Warning, haven't tested...)

Answer (score 5):

I use the following:

```
\def\restrict#1{\raise-.5ex\hbox{\ensuremath|}_{#1}}
```

because normally the vertical bar must be lowered (and not centered on the math axis as other symbols). And it doesn't need to be very big, it is the fact that it goes lower than the rest that shows that it is a restriction and not an absolute value or a divides symbol.

Comment: Since it's LaTeX, it should be `\newcommand\restrict[1]{\raisebox{-.5ex}{$|$}_{#1}}`

Answer (score 3):

I had that problem recently and I looked it up here, but since then I usually type `$f_{\big|A}$`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$f{\big|}_A$`?

Comment: I wouldn't write it like that

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer `$f\arrowvert_A$` to the above-mentioned suggested commands.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  What do you mean with above commands?

Comment: Additionally, specify the source of `\arrowvert`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `\eval{f}_A` provided by the `physics` package:

[image]

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\verb=f\restriction_A= & \verb={f|}_A= & \verb={f\bigr|}_A= & \verb=\eval{f}_A= \\
$f\restriction_A$ & ${f|}_A$ & ${f\bigr|}_A$  & $\eval{f}_A$ \\ \noalign{\vskip 1mm}
$f^{(n)}\restriction_A$ & ${f^{(n)}|}_A$ & ${f^{(n)}\bigr|}_A$  & $\eval{f^{(n)}}_A$  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```