# One more question regarding "function restriction"

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

This question is in connection with [How to typeset function restrictions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22252/how-to-typeset-function-restrictions)

There, egreg gives a [satisfactory answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22255/11601) (at least for me)

The problem is that I'd like to do the same thing with `\restriction` as delimiter instead of  `|`, but somehow I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: The problem is that the `\restriction` symbol doesn't come with larger variants.

Comment: I see. I actually don't care about the size (since usually it's the right size), but the spacing of restriction is just very bad - what could I do to change that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can say (requires `amssymb`, of course)

```
\renewcommand{\restriction}{\mathord{\upharpoonright}}
```

and the result will be as in the second line in the following picture, while the first line represents what you get now

[image]

Comment: It seems egreg has already answered every single question I can think of.

Comment: @Hermis14 Been there, done that… ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To have the restriction of $f$ to some subdomain $A$, I would suggest $f\arrowvert_A$.