# Typesetting a function restriction with a bar shorter than \big

Tags: math-mode

The question about [function restrictions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22252/how-to-typeset-function-restrictions) didn't solve my problem, nor did the related questions about [bigger parenthesis larger than Bigg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6794/about-big-parenthesis-larger-than-bigg).

I'd like to typeset a function restriction, with the vertical bar a bit lowered. `f_{\big|W}` results in something close to what I want:

[image]

To perfect it, the bar would be cut off where it reaches the baseline of the subscript symbol (in this case W). So that it doesn't reach below it.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Whatever you end up using, you should define a macro that you use like `\restr{f}{W}` or `\restr{W}{f}` and let the macro output the style you want. That way you have clearer code, and much easier to tweak in the whole document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\vrule` inside an horizontal box has the property to match the height and depth of this box. Also all dimensions (`height`, `depth`, `width`) can be explicitly specified.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[ f_{\mkern 1mu \vrule height 2ex\mkern2mu W} \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

- The spacing around the vertical bar is achieved by `\mkern` to use the math unit `mu` that adopts to the current math style automatically.
- The "W" looks a tiny bit lower than the rule. The reason is that "W" draws this tiny bit outside its character bounding box. The depth can be explicitly specified for fine-tuning.