# Broken vertical bar with kpfonts-otf using LuaLaTeX

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, kpfonts

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22255
\newcommand\restrict[2]{{% we make the whole thing an ordinary symbol
  \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace % automatically resize the bar with \right
  #1 % the function
  \vphantom{\big|} % pretend it's a little taller at normal size
  \right|_{#2} % this is the delimiter
  }}

\begin{document}

\( \restrict{f}{U} = \frac{\restrict{g}{U}}{\restrict{h}{U}} \)

\end{document}
```

One would get the following result with LuaLaTeX:

[image]

As you can see, the vertical bars in script size are broken.

Is there some way to fix this behavior?

Comment: +1. `\frac` isn't needed to create the problematic output. The code snippet `$\restrict{f}{U} \quad \scriptstyle\restrict{g}{U} \quad \scriptscriptstyle\restrict{h}{U}$` gets the job done too. :-)

Comment: Strangely, the output is correct when your file is compiled with XeLaTeX. The output is also correct when compiled with LuaLaTeX and other fonts (lmodern-math, erewhon-math, etc.).  I fail to understand what is going wrong with KpMath-Regular.otf

Comment: The bug also vanishes if `KpMath-Regular.otf` is loaded with `\setmathfont{KpMath-Regular.otf}[Renderer=Node]`.  Bug of the Basic renderer?

Comment: @Jinwen I updated the answer you refer to, leaving the phantom only in display style. Not that this solves your problem, but leads to better output anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There is an extensible recipe for the vertical bar where one piece refers to the base character. The other extensible snippets are in private slots. The font has ssty replacements for the base character but not for the other extensible snippets. Therefore, in script and scriptscript sizes there is a mismatch. Other fonts, like latin modern, have a dedicated replacement for the base character in the extensible. They don't even have ssty variants for the bar. They use scaling. If you really want dedicated script and scriptscript style extensibles all snippets should have a dedicated alternate.

Comment: Good point! It means that some fix has to be applied to the ssty variants of `|` rather than deleting them like in latin modern. The ssty variants provide better sub/sup-scripts regarding the boldness. I'll test that tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: @Jinwen The bug you pointed out is fixed in version 0.44 that I am uploading to CTAN.