# Restriction of a function: the subscript seems too low

Tags: math-mode, alignment, kpfonts

When writing the restriction of some function, sometimes the restriction area (the subscript) goes under the bottom of the vertical line (especially for the font package `kpfont-otf` I'm using).

[image]

Is there some way to ensure the subscript not to be lower than the bottom of the vertical line, or at lease raise it up a little bit?

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22252/
\newcommand\restr[2]{{% we make the whole thing an ordinary symbol
  \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace % automatically resize the bar with \right
  #1 % the function
  \littletaller % pretend it's a little taller at normal size
  \right|_{#2} % this is the delimiter
  }}

\newcommand{\littletaller}{\mathchoice{\vphantom{\big|}}{}{}{}}

\begin{document}

\[
    \restr{f}{U}=\frac{\restr{g}{U}}{\restr{h}{U}}
\]

\[
    \restr{\frac{\partial}{\partial X_i}}{P}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Subscripts are supposed to go below whatever they are subscripts for.  You could use \raisebox to raise the subscript by \depth.  Note that this will depend on the current style (\displaystyle, \textstyle, \scriptstyle or \scriptscriptstyle).

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you for the suggestions. However I don't quite understand your meaning: 1) `\raisebox` would make the content in it in text style, so did you mean that one should manually add the `$...$` and add `\scriptstyle` here? 2) Regarding `\depth`, what did you mean by "raise it by \depth"?

Comment: @JohnKormylo If I use `\raisebox` to raise the subscript, then there would still be some (now empty) vertical space under the subscript, which would lead to extra space in the upper part of `\frac`.

Answer (score 1):

If `U` is a subscript to the entire `\left...\right` group, it will be lowered below the vertical line, as explained by John Kormylo. But you can append another invisible math atom with the same depth as your formula and make `U` a subscript of that, then it will be lowered less.

The other math atom must be of type Close, because there is no space between a `\left...\right` group and a Close atom:

```tex
\newcommand\restr[2]{{% we make the whole thing an ordinary symbol
  \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace % automatically resize the bar with \right
  #1 % the function
  \littletaller % pretend it's a little taller at normal size
  \right|\mathclose{\vphantom{#1}}_{#2} % this is the delimiter
  }}
```

[image]

In `kpfonts-otf` the delimiters seem too small relative to the formula they enclose. You can force bigger delimiters with `\delimiterfactor=1100` after the `\begin{document}`:

[image]

But this feels like a hack.

### Further analysis

In the math formula `\left.g\right|` (without the `\delimiterfactor` hack), the vertical bar in `kpfonts-otf` is 1.25pt shorter than the one in Computer Modern. Moreover the Computer Modern bar is already centered w.r.t. to the math axis, whereas the `kpfonts-otf` bar must be raised by 1.925pt, amplifying the effect that it does not go low enough.

`kpfonts-otf`

```
\TU/KpMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 
\vbox(8.85+0.0)x3.09, shifted 1.925, direction TLT
.\hbox(7.13+1.72)x3.09, direction TLT
..\TU/KpMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 |
```

Computer Modern

```
\OML/cmm/m/it/10 g
\kern0.35878 (italic)
\hbox(7.5+2.5)x2.77779, direction TLT
.\OMS/cmsy/m/n/10 j
```

Comment: Thank you for this. However, it works fine for ComputerModern but strangely for `kpfonts-otf` it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: The right delimiter (the vertical bar) after the `g` seems not big enough in `kpfonts-otf`. According to rule 19 in appendix G of The TeXbook, it should be roughly twice as big as the depth of `g` below the math axis.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660965/255231