# Sizing of vertical bar delimiters by kpfonts

Tags: math-mode, delimiters, kpfonts

This is a follow-up question to [Restriction of a function: the subscript seems too low](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/660851).

Typesetting the following math formulas with kpfonts

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
\begin{document}
$\left.g\right\vert, \left.g\right\Vert$
\end{document}
```

produces a vertical bar that does not go sufficiently low to cover the descender of `g`. By contrast, the double vertical bar goes low enough.

[image]

The single bar is a single character:

```
\TU/KpMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 
\vbox(8.85+0.0)x3.09, shifted 1.925, direction TLT
.\hbox(7.13+1.72)x3.09, direction TLT
..\TU/KpMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 |
```

The double bar is a constructed from an extensible character:

```
\TU/KpMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 
\vbox(12.0+0.0)x5.18, shifted 3.5, direction TLT
.\hbox(0.11+4.61)x5.18, direction TLT
..\TU/KpMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 
.\glue -1.57 plus 1.37001
.\hbox(7.13+1.72)x5.18, direction TLT
..\TU/KpMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 ‖
```

When typesetting the same with Computer Modern instead of kpfonts, both vertical bars behave the same (a single character in both cases):

[image]

```
\OML/cmm/m/it/10 g
\kern0.35878 (italic)
\hbox(7.5+2.5)x2.77779, direction TLT
.\OMS/cmsy/m/n/10 j
```

```
\OML/cmm/m/it/10 g
\kern0.35878 (italic)
\hbox(7.5+2.5)x5.00002, direction TLT
.\OMS/cmsy/m/n/10 k
```

Why does the single vertical bar in kpfonts not behave in the same way as the double vertical bar?

### Additional remark after reading the answer

The answer says

> `\vert` is not extended (this is a bug)

But the vertical bar after a taller formula

```tex
$$\left.g\over h\right\vert$$
```

*is* extended:

```
\hbox(11.48+6.96)x7.62999, direction TLT
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x1.2, shifted -2.5, direction TLT
.\vbox(11.48+6.96)x5.23, direction TLT
..\hbox(4.64+2.59)x5.23, glue set 0.28fil, direction TLT
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
...\TU/KpMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
..\kern1.5 (font)
..\rule(0.5+0.0)x*
..\kern1.89 (font)
..\hbox(7.22+0.1)x5.23, direction TLT
...\TU/KpMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 ℎ
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x1.2, shifted -2.5, direction TLT
\vbox(17.03398+0.0)x3.09, glue set 0.68758, shifted 6.017, direction TLT
.\hbox(0.11+4.61)x3.09, direction TLT
..\TU/KpMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 
.\glue -1.57 plus 1.37001
.\hbox(0.11+4.61)x3.09, direction TLT
..\TU/KpMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 
.\glue -1.57 plus 1.37001
.\hbox(7.13+1.72)x3.09, direction TLT
..\TU/KpMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 |
```

Comment: If I understand your posting correctly, your beef is *not* with the vertical bars drawn by `\left.g\right\vert` and `\left.g\right\Vert` having different sizes. Instead, it appears to be with the fact that the bar drawn by  `\left.g\right\vert` "does not go sufficiently low to cover the descender of `g`", i.e., it's too short. The height of the vertical bars is a choice variable for the font designer. It's well known that the `\vert` and `\Vert` symbols drawn by Palatino-type math fonts are quite short -- and, in particular, "do not go sufficiently low to cover the descender of `g`".

Comment: But `\Vert` _does_ go low enough, thus behaving differently from `\vert`.

Comment: I've rephrased the last sentence, not sure if that is what you meant.

Comment: You wrote, "But `\Vert` *does* go low enough, thus behaving differently from `\vert`". Sorry, but that's *false*: Both `\vert` and `\Vert` draw bars that have the exact same depth -- which you have criticized as as being "too short", since they don't cover the descender of `g`. What you have come across is that `\left.g\right\vert` and `\left.g\right\Vert` create symbols of different heights. To me, the question is not why the symbol drawn by `\left.g\right\vert` is too short; instead, it shoud be why the symbol drawn by `\left.g\right\Vert` is needlessly tall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\vert` delimiter has wrong parameters in the `GlyphCompositionVertical` field (fontforge) which makes the extension fail on this case. The other two `\Vert` and `\Vvert` are fine.

To make it clear: in your picture the `\right\vert` is not extended, it is a raw `\vert` while the `\right\Vert` is composed of `\Vert` plus a vertical extension. As both are (automatically) centered on the math axis, the `\right\Vert` goes deeper down and higher up.

Thanks for pointing this out, it will be fixed in the next version of `kpfonts-otf`.

**Follow up:** should `\vert` be extended or not?

The decision is made by the TeX engine: the extension is triggered if and only if `g` descends lower than `\vert` (vertically centred on the maths axis); this explains the different results between `newpxmath` and `kpfonts-otf`

Here is what you get with `newpxmath` (the red line shows the maths axis):

[image]

And with the current (v.045) `kpfonts-otf`:

[image]

As mentioned above, `\vert` is not extended (this is a bug) but `\Vert`, which has the same height and depth as `\vert`, is extended as expected.

Note: the gap between the total heights of `\vert` and `\Vert` above is too large. I will add intermediate sizes for a smoother transition.

Here is the source of these tests:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,iftex}
\iftutex
  \usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
\else
  \usepackage{newpxmath}
\fi
\newlength{\height}
\newlength{\depth}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
{\tiny
 \settoheight{\height}{h}        ht(h)=\the\height ;
 \settoheight{\height}{$\vert$}  ht(vert)=\the\height

 \settodepth {\depth}{g}         dp(g)=\the\depth ;
 \settodepth {\depth}{$\vert$}   dp(vert)=\the\depth
}

\makebox[0pt]{\color{red}\rule[2.5pt]{\textwidth}{0.2pt}}%
$\left.h\right\vert$, $\left.g\right\vert$,
\iftutex$\left.g\right\Vert$\fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also my additional remark.

Comment: `\vert` misses *small* extensions where required, not big ones.